# 403 - forbidden error when add class library to WCF web role on Azure Project

Tags: wcf, class, azure, http-status-code-403

Open VS as admin, I create a solution, add new Cloud Azure Project then pick WCF service web role and then run it, everything is fine, I could access default services through browser nicely, however, when add new blank class library as new DAL project to the solution and run it, I have 403 error says "You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."

what is going wrong?

thanks

P.S (with or without adding EMDX with proper db access to class lib, it came out something)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9411719/182371:

> As for the Access Denied error:
>
> - it could be just an IIS default setting to disable browsing. To resolve that, just navigate to that web site in IIS, find Directory
>     Browsing icon, and press Enable. You will at least see the files
>     inside that directory.
> - Also try not only 127.0.0.1:81, buta specific document inside that folder, like 127.0.0.1:81/Default.aspx
> - Take into account the fact that there's sometimes some mess with the ports. You see that in the error message it's port 82, but in your
>     browser it's port 81. So make sure you're using the right port. Or,
>     even better, in your service definition try to use some non-standard
>     port for this to avoid remapping.